# Множественное число слов "учитель", "служитель" и подобных

Tags: грамматика, склонение

Для такого рода слов — учитель, служитель, строитель, ваятель и т. д., — есть ли правило, следуя которому ставится ударение для множественной формы?

Учители или учителя? Служители или служителя?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Правильно учител**я**, но это редкий, едва ли не единичный случай для слов на -ель. 
Все остальные не меняют место ударения: cлуж**и**тели, стро**и**тели, ва**я**тели.

А вообще все слова с сомнительной формой множественного числа надо проверять по словарю, единых закономерностей тут нет.

> Есть ли правило, которому следуя, ставится ударение в множественной форме слова?

Если существительное мужского рода имеет во множественном числе окончание -А(-Я), то на него **всегда** падает ударение. Это правило имеет характер орфоэпического закона и выполняется даже для разговорных и просторечных образаваний типа "шоферА", "тортА" и т. п.

Можно даже сказать, что именно в этом смещении ударения и есть суть рассматриваемого явления, а фонетический переход -Ы(-И) в -А(-Я) скорее вторичен.

Что касается нормативности самой формы, то, как уже сказал, в общем случае может помочь только орфоэпический словарь. Но для существительных на -ель: "учителя" - исключение из общей закономерности.

UPD

Я согласен с Niemand, что в значении "главы учения" (если признать его сохранившемся в языке) или, лучше сказать, "основатели (философских) школ" по отношению к своим последователям и ученикам - учители. Это значение сохранило историческую форму множественного. Но тут есть одна сложность. Поскольку к основному значению ("преподаватель") относятся далеко не одни школьные работники, а ко второму - отнюдь не только Лао Цзы и Аристотель (у  Кузнецова там вообще "человек, обладающий авторитетом" - [учитель | gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?word=%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&all=x)), разницу между значениями уловить весьма сложно.

Отсюда есть предположение, что тенденция переноса ударения во множественном числе распространится на оба значения. Забавно, что упомянутый выше в скобках Кузнецов, пользуясь, видимо, своим определением, уже сейчас не видит разницу в словоформах этих двух значений. Сразу скажу, что к этой рекомендации Кузнецова, как и ко всем его орфоэпическим новациям, следует относиться очень осторожно. Но как пища для размышления и оно сгодится.

Answer (score 1):

Учителя – преподаватели, учители – главы учений.

Comment: Служитель, строитель, ваятель и т. д.?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: учителя́ (в школе), учи́тели (духовные), служители, строители, ваятели.

**Пояснение**

1) Существительные м. р. во мн. числе И. п. имеют основное окончание **Ы/И** и вариантное окончание **А/Я**, причем вариантное окончание **А/Я** имеют многие слова с односложной основой: бок – бока, лес – леса,  снег – снега, а также некоторые слова с неодносложной основой (в этом случае ударение обычно падает на второй слог от конца основы):  берег – берега, город – города, парус – паруса.

2) Окончания **А/Я** и **Ы/И** могут различаться **по стилю** и **по смыслу**.

А. Различение по стилю: што́рмы (нейтр.) и шторма́ (разг.).
Б. Различение по смыслу или по области употребления: ла́гери (политические) и лагеря́ (для отдыха), учи́тели (духовные) и учителя́ (в школе), образа́ (церк.) и о́бразы (в литературе и искусстве) и т. д.

3) **Слова на ЛЬ**. Так как ударение в этих существительных падает на предпоследний слог, то возможны различные варианты окончаний:

вензель – вензеля́, дупель – дупеля́ — **только вариантное** окончание Я;
вентиль – ве́нтили, табель – та́бели, служитель – служи́тели, строитель – строи́тели и т. д. — **только основное** окончание И;
вексель – ве́ксели и векселя́,  китель – ки́тели и кителя́ — **два варианта** окончаний.

Comment: Мне кажется, что надо поправить ответ. Если слова на -ТЕЛЬ, то много лишних примеров; если же на -ЕЛЬ, то лишний только _вент**иль_**.

Comment: Спасибо, ответ поправлен. Правда, мне кажется, что его надо не только поправить, но и заодно удалить: приведенная информация никого не заинтересовала.

Comment: Не удаляйте. Я позволила себе "подкрасивить" Ваш ответ (мне кажется, что визуально ТАК лучше воспринимается). И оценить (в шестнадцатом году меня еще не было на сайте).

Comment: Спасибо, Римма, теперь уж точно не удалю.